# Triangle angle classification

Tags: python

I need to make a function to make that will give me an angle classification like acute right or obtuse and I need it to loop until the user wants to exit the function:

this is my code so far:

```
side_a = float(input('Enter length of side a: '))
side_b = float(input('Enter length of side b: '))
side_c = float(input('Enter length of side c: '))
def is_valid_triangle(a,b,c): 
    if a+b>=c and b+c>=a and c+a>=b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Function definition for type of triangle 
def type_of_triangle(a,b,c):
    if a==b and b==c:
print('Triangle is Equilateral.')
    elif a==b or b==c or a==c:
        print('Triangle is Isosceles.')
    else:
        print('Triangle is Scalane')
 
    return False
if is_valid_triangle(side_a, side_b, side_c):
    type_of_triangle(side_a, side_b, side_c)
else:
    print('Tringle is not possible from given sides.')


def triangle_angle (a, b, c, ) : 
  a = int(input ("enter side a: "))
  b = int(input("enter side b : "))
  c = int(input("enter side c : "))
```

Comment: What part exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I cant figure out how I can create a function that will tell me if the triangle is acute right or an obtuse angle using the side lenghts given my the user

Comment: Does this help guide you with the math? https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/triangle-angle

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know how to constantly loop code.

You can use:

```py
try:
  while True:
    pass # replace with whatever code you want to run
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print('Exiting...')
```

Which will constantly loop until the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I think this answers your question.